# Disable user after registration and allow admin to confirm it

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

There is a lot of questions at stack about this problem, but to be honest - no one is working for me (I am using Symfony 3.3 and FOSUserBundle 2.x).

What I need to achive:

- user successfully registers at my page
- his account is set automatically to default (no email is sent)
- admin can activate/enable that account from his admin panel

I have created an EventListener but it won't work.. I can't even manipulate user object to change `enabled` status ...

```
#config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

And event listener:

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    private $em;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $route, UserManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->router = $route;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED=> ['onRegistrationConfirmed', 999],
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE => 'onRegistrationFailure'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('app.registration.succes');
        $response = new JsonResponse(['redirectUrl' => $url]);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    public function onRegistrationFailure(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $array = array('success' => false, 'message' => (string)$event->getForm()->getErrors(true, true));
        $response = new JsonResponse($array, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirmed(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        /**
         * this one is no working.. after registration account is enabled anyway...
         */
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $user->setSalt('test');
        $this->em->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

Just call it on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` because `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` is triggered only when user click activation link on his email, which I'm not sending to him.

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    private $em;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $route, UserManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->router = $route;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE => 'onRegistrationFailure'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $this->em->updateUser($user);

        $url = $this->router->generate('app.registration.succes');
        $response = new JsonResponse(['redirectUrl' => $url]);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    public function onRegistrationFailure(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $array = array('success' => false, 'message' => (string)$event->getForm()->getErrors(true, true));
        $response = new JsonResponse($array, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```